# Is there any library for solrj to create query in easy way

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, querydsl

I am looking for some userful tool to create query, something like querydsl (http://www.querydsl.com/) as alternative to criteria query for jpa.

Query dsl have got module for lucene api, but not for solr. Is there any library or tools , which allow in simply way create query using solrj ??

Comment: Querydsl doesn't support Solr, but you could ask in the Querydsl Google Group if other users have similar needs, then the development of Querydsl Solr could be considered https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/querydsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for [Spring Data Solr module](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-solr) which can help build model objects and handling the queries and results through these objects